# Javascript setInterval with web worker slows down in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, setinterval, web-worker, countdowntimer

I am implementing a countdown timer with Javascript setInterval and web worker. It is working fine in desktop but in the mobile browser the timer is slowing down when the browser is minimized (inactive mode).

Is there a way out to prevent the setInerval slow down issue in mobile?

Here is the glimpse of my code:

**script.js**

```
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function (event) {
  if( document[hidden] === false ){
      // distance is a value of difference between current time and the end time

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60)) / 60);
      var seconds = Math.floor(distance % 60);

      var secondsLeft = (days * 24 * 3600) + (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;

      startTimer(distance, secondsLeft);
  }
});


function startTimer(distance, secondsLeft)
{
   // First check whether Web Workers are supported
   if (typeof(Worker)!=="undefined"){
      // Check whether Web Worker has been created. If not, create a new Web Worker based on the Javascript file simple-timer.js
      if(w == null){
        
        w = new Worker("../js/timer-worker.js");

        w.postMessage({ 
            'distance': distance,
            'secondsLeft': secondsLeft
        });
      }
      // Update timer div with output from Web Worker
      w.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log(event.data.time_left_str);
      };
   } else {
      // Web workers are not supported by your browser
      console.log('Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers ...');
   }
}
```

**timer-worker.js**

```
var timerStart = true;

function myTimer(distance)
{
   function pad(n) {
      return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
   }

   var hours = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
   var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60)) / 60);
   var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (60));

   var total_seconds = (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;

   if( hours > 0 ){
      time_left_str = pad(hours) + " hrs " + pad(minutes) + " mins " + pad(seconds) + " secs ";
   }
   else if( minutes > 0 ){
      time_left_str = pad(minutes) + " mins " + pad(seconds) + " secs ";
   }
   else{
      time_left_str = pad(seconds) + " secs ";
   }

   // return output to Web Worker
   postMessage({
      'time_left_str': time_left_str,
      'total_seconds': total_seconds,
      'distance_changed': distance
   });
}


if (timerStart){
   distance = null;
   secondsLeft = null;

   self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if(typeof(event.data.distance)!=="undefined"){
         distance = event.data.distance;
      }
      if(typeof(event.data.secondsLeft)!=="undefined"){
         secondsLeft = event.data.secondsLeft;
      }
      
   }, false);

   // get current time
   var d0=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // repeat myTimer(d0) every 100 ms
   myVar = setInterval(function(e){
      //console.log('distance :: ' + distance);
      myTimer(distance, secondsLeft);

      distance--;
   }, 1000);
   // timer should not start anymore since it has been started
   timerStart = false;
}
```

Comment: Both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are **not** guaranteed to be on time, see [this section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays) for more details. There is no way to avoid this, since this isn't a flaw but a perk from the user's side: random websites can't just hog up the browser arbitrarily.

Comment: The requirement I have is to make sure the timer runs irrespective of the browser being inactive in mobile. As I said, it is working perfectly in all the browsers I tested in desktop. There problem is there with the mobile browsers only. Is there anyway out?

Answer (score 1):

Why would your countdown need to run every second even when the browser is not displayed ? I think this isn't your need, but to display an accurante countdown when the user is watching it.

Instead of decrementing your counter on every timer hoping it would execute precisely every seconds, you should just recompute the distance from the moment the page first loaded, preventing any hazard effect to occur :

```
//happens on the loading of the page
var d0 = new Date();
var initDistance = //compute initial distance here
var distance = initDistance;

// ... in the refresh function
    var distance = //recompute distance based on initDistance and the difference between new Date() and d0

// do the same for secondLeft if needed.
```

Comment: I needed the server time here which I am fetching through ajax.
```var d0 = new Date();``` will not work in my case.

Comment: Then why not just fetch it once, store the corresponding client time and use both of them as reference ?

Comment: No, I can't fetch it once. It is an auction portal and the end time of the auction keeps changing based on some other conditions. 
So I have to fetch auction end time through ajax and calculate the difference between server time and the auction end time.

Comment: Ok, first I think you need to put that information on your question as this is very important. Second, is there a reason why you spam requests and do not use stuff like websockets ? If you can only pull my recommendation would be to do a mix : countdown every seconds and every x seconds, ask the server for a resync.